# /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:106:10: error: ‘__builtin_strncpy’

Tags: c++, ubuntu, gcc, compiler-errors

I'm trying to Build Qemu & Xen for XenGT on Ubuntu 20.04 following this tutorial :

https://github.com/intel/gvt-linux/wiki/GVTg_Setup_Guide#332-build-qemu--xen-for-xengt

because I want to share the integrated GPU with a xen VM.

The main hardware components of my PC are the following :

**CPU I9-9900k**

**Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 630 (Desktop 9 Series) (rev 02)**

**IVIDIA Corporation TU102 [GeForce RTX 2080 Ti] (rev a1)**

The compilation gave no errors until this point :

```
root@ziomario-z390aoruspro:/etc/xen/igvtg-xen# make install-tools

......

make libs
make[5]: ingresso nella directory «/etc/xen/igvtg-xen/tools/libxc»
rm -f _paths.h.tmp; echo "#define sbindir "/usr/sbin"" >>_paths.h.tmp; echo "#define bindir "/usr/bin"" >>_paths.h.tmp; echo "#define LIBEXEC "/usr/lib/xen"" >>_paths.h.tmp; echo "#define LIBEXEC_BIN "/usr/lib/xen/bin"" >>_paths.h.tmp; echo "#define libdir "/usr/lib"" >>_paths.h.tmp; echo "#define SHAREDIR "/usr/share"" >>_paths.h.tmp; echo "#define XENFIRMWAREDIR "/usr/lib/xen/boot"" >>_paths.h.tmp; echo "#define XEN_CONFIG_DIR "/etc/xen"" >>_paths.h.tmp; echo "#define XEN_SCRIPT_DIR "/etc/xen/scripts"" >>_paths.h.tmp; echo "#define XEN_LOCK_DIR "/var/lock"" >>_paths.h.tmp; echo "#define XEN_RUN_DIR "/var/run/xen"" >>_paths.h.tmp; echo "#define XEN_PAGING_DIR "/var/lib/xen/xenpaging"" >>_paths.h.tmp; echo "#define XEN_DUMP_DIR "/var/lib/xen/dump"" >>_paths.h.tmp; echo "#define XEN_LOG_DIR "/var/log/xen"" >>_paths.h.tmp; echo "#define XEN_LIB_DIR "/var/lib/xen"" >>_paths.h.tmp; echo "#define XEN_RUN_STORED "/var/run/xenstored"" >>_paths.h.tmp; if ! cmp -s _paths.h.tmp paths.h; then mv -f paths.h.tmp paths.h; else rm -f paths.h.tmp; fi
gcc -m64 -DBUILD_ID -fno-strict-aliasing -std=gnu99 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wno-unused-local-typedefs -O2 -fomit-frame-pointer -D__XEN_INTERFACE_VERSION=XEN_LATEST_INTERFACE_VERSION -MMD -MF .xc_pm.o.d -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_GNU_SOURCE -I../../xen/common/libelf -Werror -Wmissing-prototypes -I. -I./include -I/etc/xen/igvtg-xen/tools/libxc/../../tools/include -D__XEN_TOOLS -pthread -I/etc/xen/igvtg-xen/tools/libxc/../../tools/libs/toollog/include -I/etc/xen/igvtg-xen/tools/libxc/../../tools/include -I/etc/xen/igvtg-xen/tools/libxc/../../tools/libs/evtchn/include -I/etc/xen/igvtg-xen/tools/libxc/../../tools/include -I/etc/xen/igvtg-xen/tools/libxc/../../tools/libs/devicemodel/include -I/etc/xen/igvtg-xen/tools/libxc/../../tools/include -include /etc/xen/igvtg-xen/tools/libxc/../../tools/config.h -I/etc/xen/igvtg-xen/tools/libxc/../../tools/libs/call/include -I/etc/xen/igvtg-xen/tools/libxc/../../tools/include -I/etc/xen/igvtg-xen/tools/libxc/../../tools/libs/foreignmemory/include -I/etc/xen/igvtg-xen/tools/libxc/../../tools/include -I/etc/xen/igvtg-xen/tools/libxc/../../tools/libs/gnttab/include -I/etc/xen/igvtg-xen/tools/libxc/../../tools/include -c -o xc_pm.o xc_pm.c
In file included from /usr/include/string.h:495,
from xc_private.h:24,
from xc_pm.c:22:
In function ‘strncpy’,
inlined from ‘xc_set_cpufreq_gov’ at xc_pm.c:308:5:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:106:10: error: ‘__builtin_strncpy’ specified bound 16 equals destination size [-Werror=stringop-truncation]
106 | return __builtin___strncpy_chk (__dest, __src, __len, __bos (__dest));
| ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
make[5]: *** [/etc/xen/igvtg-xen/tools/libxc/../../tools/Rules.mk:222: xc_pm.o] Errore 1
make[5]: uscita dalla directory «/etc/xen/igvtg-xen/tools/libxc»
make[4]: *** [Makefile:184: build] Errore 2
make[4]: uscita dalla directory «/etc/xen/igvtg-xen/tools/libxc»
make[3]: *** [/etc/xen/igvtg-xen/tools/../tools/Rules.mk:246: subdir-install-libxc] Errore 2
make[3]: uscita dalla directory «/etc/xen/igvtg-xen/tools»
make[2]: *** [/etc/xen/igvtg-xen/tools/../tools/Rules.mk:241: subdirs-install] Errore 2
make[2]: uscita dalla directory «/etc/xen/igvtg-xen/tools»
make[1]: *** [Makefile:74: install] Errore 2
make[1]: uscita dalla directory «/etc/xen/igvtg-xen/tools»
make: *** [Makefile:127: install-tools] Errore 2
```

I see that this bug is widespread. How can I fix it ? Im not so skilled. I didn't find any solution. Can someone help me ? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this:
"cc1: all warnings being treated as errors"
And you can find these in build.html:
"By default, the JDK has a strict approach where warnings from the compiler is considered errors which fail the build. For very new or very old compiler versions, this can trigger new classes of warnings, which thus fails the build. Run configure with --disable-warnings-as-errors to turn of this behavior. (The warnings will still show, but not make the build fail.)"
so we know that the JDK treats the warning as an error and terminates the building. you just need "make clean" and "bash configure --disable-warnings-as-errors" to regenerate the configuration